# Do I use non-normalized or normalized fft output from R to compute phase angle?

Tags: r, signal-processing, fourier-transform

Is R's `fft()` output normalized or not? In other words, do I have to normalize the output first before computing the phase angle using `atan2()`?

On a related point, does does anyone know what phase shift is used in R's `fft()` function?

Answer (score 2):

Normalization is multiplication of the whole output by a real number. Multiplying a complex number by a real number has no effect on the phase of the complex number. You don't need to normalize if all you need is the phase.

Comment: Oh my goodness. Of course. I am a freaking idiot.